# Error "setting an array element with a sequence" when converting an object array to integer array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, valueerror

I have an array like this:

```
from numpy import *
a=zeros(3, dtype=object)
for i in range(3):
    a[i]=array([i,i], dtype=int64)
```

So `a` is basically:

```
array([array([0, 0], dtype=int64), array([1, 1], dtype=int64),
       array([2, 2], dtype=int64)], dtype=object)
```

I want to convert it to a 2-dimensional pure numpy integer array of shape (3,2), which should be:

```
array([[0, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [2, 2]], dtype=int64)
```

However, when I used `a.astype(int64)`, it reported an error:

```
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#11>", line 1, in <module>
    a.astype(np.int64)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I searched for this error message (which is usually caused by dtypes and sizes not matching). However in this example, everything matched.

Of course, I could convert everything to a list, then convert the list to an array. But that is not elegant (and sometimes really slow).

```
b=[]          
for i in range(3):
    b.append(a[i].tolist())
c=array(b, dtype=int64)
```

This yields correct results, but the code isn't elegant.

Are there any other solutions?

Note that I'm talking about the *conversion* rather than the *creation* of such an array.

Comment: If you just want to create an array you expected, you can use this code : `a=np.array([range(3), ] *2 ,dtype='int64').T`

Comment: It's not the creation of the array that matters. I'm talking about the conversion of the array of `object`s into a pure integer array. Sorry for inconvenience.